# integrate $\int \frac{(1+x)^2}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{(1+x)^2}{\sqrt{x}}$$

I know it can be solved $\int \frac{(1+x)^2}{\sqrt{x}}=\int \frac{x^2+2x+1}{\sqrt{x}}=\int x^{\frac{3}{2}}+2\int x^{\frac{1}{2}}+\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2}{5}x^{\frac{5}{2}}+\frac{4}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+2\sqrt{x}+c$

Is there a faster way?

Comment: That is the fastest way. It only uses some basic properties of integration and algebra.

Comment: The only faster way is maybe Mathematica.....and even then

Comment: You could do a trigonometric substitution $x=\tan^2u$, but this is undoubtedly a slower method.